# how can i add a row datagridview programaticaly

Tags: vb.net

can i add a row and write data in datagridview after used theese codes?

İ can write manuel but i can't write with button

````
 .Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = CARKOD.Text
                .Rows(s).Cells(1).Value = UNVAN.Text
                .Rows(s).Cells(2).Value = ACIKLAMA

 
With MAHSUP
            Dim dt1 = New DataTable()
            myDA1 = New OleDbDataAdapter(cm1)
            Dim builder1 As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(myDA1)
            myDataSet1 = New DataSet()
            myDA1.Fill(myDataSet1, "CARTH001")
            .DataSource = myDataSet1.Tables("CARTH001").DefaultView
        End With ```
````

Comment: When the grid has a `DataSource` as it appears it does, then, to programmatically add rows to the grid, your code needs to add the rows to the `DataSource` NOT the grid.

Comment: can u learn me what can i do it

Comment: Sorry I am unable to “learn” for you. The `DataTable` that you need to add a row to appears to be … `myDataSet1.Tables("CARTH001")` … The documentation to “add” a new row to the table can be found at … [DataTable.NewRow Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.newrow?view=netcore-3.1)    Google is your friend, there are many examples of how to add rows to a `DataTable`.

Comment: i'm sory i write wrong :(

can you teach i want say

Comment: I add it but now icant write anythig
İt gives this error
The 'Value' field of type 'DBNull' is 'ReadOnly'.

Comment: Show what you tried by “editing” your question. Do not add the code as a comment. Click the “edit” link below your question and add the code that is not working.

Comment: ```  Dim MyNewRow As DataRow
                MyNewRow = .NewRow
                With MyNewRow
                   
                    .Item(0).Value = CARKOD.Text
                    .Item(1).Value = UNVAN.Text
                    .Item(2).Value = ACIKLAMA  ```

Comment: Damn @Caius Jard … I am often critical of others when not paying attention to posted info and I have to blush when caught NOT practicing what I preach. You are correct, I neglected to note that the posted data source is a … `.DefaultView` `DataView` … As you noted and I can now confirm, my previous comment using the trycast with a `DataTable` in this context… will NOT work using a `DataTable`. I thank you Caius Jard for pointing this out. Feel free in the future to point out my mistakes. I prefer to delete an answer/comment that is not relevant or worse… just wrong as this case. Thank you.

Comment: This should work using a `DataView` …  `Dim dv = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataView)`   `dv.Table.Rows.Add(CARKOD.Text, UNVAN.Text, ACIKLAMA.Text)`

Comment: @johng No probs! As my earlier comment no longer applies I've removed it, FYI

Comment: i tried it but ididnt worked

Comment: Show us what you tried and what is not working. PLEASE add the code to your original question... DO NOT add the code as a comment.

Comment: thanks for all i did it
its working i adapted your codes :)

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of data-binding is that the control displays the contents of the data source. It then provides a UI for the user to interact with that data source. If you want to make changes to the data in code, you work with the data source, NOT to UI.

When binding a `DataTable` to a `DataGridView`, the correct course of action is to use a `BindingSource` between them and use that to access the data in code. You can add the `BindingSource` in the designer and then bind like this:

```vb
Dim myDataTable As New DataTable

myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
```

To add a row, you call `AddNew` on the `BindingSource`. That will return the new item, which is a `DataRowView`. You populate that and then commit it to the underlying `DataTable` and the `DataGridView` will display it, e.g.

```vb
Dim newRow = DirectCast(myBindingSource.AddNew(), DataRowView)

newRow("SomeColumn") = someValue
myBindingSource.EndEdit()
```

To summarise, DO NOT use the `DefaultView` of the `DataTable` directly. DO bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and DO bind that to your UI. DO always use the `BindingSource` to manipulate and navigate the bound data in code.

Comment: i hope i explain what i want;
i have access mdb 
i use query for fill datagridview 
then
when i change or add a new row(s) my codes must update acces mdb

Comment: Regardless of how you make the changes to the `DataTable`, you use the same data adapter to save the changes as you did to retrieve the data in the first place. `Fill` retrieves data and `Update` saves changes. If you have an issue with that part then you should ask a new question about that specifically because that is a different topic to adding a row to a bound grid.